# Backup MySQL database with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have been looking into the user guide which came with CodeIgniter. I became very interested with the `dbutil()` method. Particularly the following line of code:

```
// Load the DB utility class
$this->load->dbutil();

// Backup your entire database and assign it to a variable
$backup =& $this->dbutil->backup(); 

// Load the file helper and write the file to your server
$this->load->helper('file');
write_file('/path/to/mybackup.gz', $backup); 

// Load the download helper and send the file to your desktop
$this->load->helper('download');
force_download('mybackup.gz', $backup);
```

It is supposed to backup the currently loaded MySQL database. But unfortunately, it is not working and I get the following message:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$dbutil
>
> Filename: views/view.php
>
> Line Number: 10
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function backup() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\views\view.php on line 10

What am I missing here? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is the main DB class loaded (autoloaded or loaded through `$this->load->database();`)? Also, how come you are getting this error on a view, shouldn't this backup code be on a controller?

Comment: @muttalebm you need to remove last two lines from your above code.

Comment: Code should be executed inside a controller, not a view.

Comment: Wow! After 6 years and 8 months, still this question is active. Based on my experience I believe backing up your database with PHP is a bad Idea. 
From code igniter 3.1 docs `Due to the limited execution time and memory available to PHP, backing up very large databases may not be possible.** If your database is very large you might need to backup directly from your SQL server via the command line, or have your server admin do it for you if you do not have root privileges.**`
I hope this question and the answers by this great community was helpful for someone.

Answer (score 32):

Try this, You can change format zip to gz if you like :)

```
$this->load->dbutil();

$prefs = array(     
    'format'      => 'zip',             
    'filename'    => 'my_db_backup.sql'
    );


$backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs); 

$db_name = 'backup-on-'. date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") .'.zip';
$save = 'pathtobkfolder/'.$db_name;

$this->load->helper('file');
write_file($save, $backup); 


$this->load->helper('download');
force_download($db_name, $backup);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Saleem. I was looking for the zip format. But my original problem was fixed. I was trying to call the dbutil() method from the view which should have been done from the controller. A very idiotic moment for me :( Anyways thanks for your help buddy :D

Comment: No problem, Good to hear that you have managed to solve the issue. Take care

Comment: Thanks a lot, well now i have another issue how can i update database from one to another one,

Comment: @Saleem I coded same as above, but it works me for test environment which contains data in KB's, when I'm applying same for my actual database it wont take backup that having data in MB's (25+ MB). Is there any memory limit to take a backup ?

Comment: @GaneshAher Please refer to docs at https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html and note from docs "Due to the limited execution time and memory available to PHP, backing up very large databases may not be possible. If your database is very large you might need to backup directly from your SQL server via the command line, or have your server admin do it for you if you do not have root privileges."

Comment: my normal database size is 32 mb but with this method my database downloaded 97mb and showing error when uploading form 'localhost/phpmyadmin'

Comment: That's quite much difference. You can try gz or refer to the official user guide https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/utilities.html#database-backup-notes

Answer (score 7):

doing that using php will only work for very small databases. You will very fast run into memory limits - if you increase that other performance problems.

What works best is to create a dump using mysqldump:

```
header('Content-type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="dbbackup.sql.gz"');
passthru("mysqldump --user=xx --host=xx --password=xx dbname | gzip");
```

of course you must have the required permissions to do that.

Comment: Thanks but I am working with a small database over a office network

Comment: Why use `passthru` over `exec` here?

Answer (score 7):

```
//load helpers

$this->load->helper('file');
$this->load->helper('download');
$this->load->library('zip');

//load database
$this->load->dbutil();

//create format
$db_format=array('format'=>'zip','filename'=>'backup.sql');

$backup=& $this->dbutil->backup($db_format);

// file name

$dbname='backup-on-'.date('d-m-y H:i').'.zip';
$save='assets/db_backup/'.$dbname;

// write file

write_file($save,$backup);

// and force download
force_download($dbname,$backup);
```

Comment: Only on change needed ":" is not working as a file name for zip. Had to replace with "-" and it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
function backup($fileName='db_backup.zip'){
    // Load the DB utility class
    $this->load->dbutil();

    // Backup your entire database and assign it to a variable
    $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup();

    // Load the file helper and write the file to your server
    $this->load->helper('file');
    write_file(FCPATH.'/downloads/'.$fileName, $backup);

    // Load the download helper and send the file to your desktop
    $this->load->helper('download');
    force_download($fileName, $backup);
}
```

Easy way to backup database using codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

```
public function db_backup()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $this->load->library('zip');
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $db_format=array('format'=>'zip','filename'=>'my_db_backup.sql');
    $backup=& $this->dbutil->backup($db_format);
    $dbname='backup-on-'.date('Y-m-d').'.zip';
    $save='assets/db_backup/'.$dbname;
    write_file($save,$backup);
    force_download($dbname,$backup);

}`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky enough to have one of the `exec()`, `shell_exec()`, `system()` or `passthru()` enabled on your server. Maybe you would want to use the following:

```
public function db_backup()
{
    $DBUSER=$this->db->username;
    $DBPASSWD=$this->db->password;
    $DATABASE=$this->db->database;

    $filename = $DATABASE . "-" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") . ".sql.gz";
    $mime = "application/x-gzip";

    header( "Content-Type: " . $mime );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"' );

    // $cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip --best";   
    $cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD --no-create-info --complete-insert $DATABASE | gzip --best";

    passthru( $cmd );

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...it has been tested...if you are going to use mysqli then it will works fine...you may put your code in your controller or model but i suggest to keep this one in your_model & call this function from your_controller...

```
public function db_backup()
{
       $this->load->dbutil();   
       $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup();  
       $this->load->helper('file');
       write_file('your_file_path/your_DB.zip', $backup); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am extremely new to CodeIgniter but I succeeded to do this backup. Try this, it will work successfully and is very easy to implement. Write the code in your controller and call the function from your view page which use for backup. Get set, go and you are done.

```
function dbbackup()
{
    $this->load->dbutil();   
    $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup();  
    $this->load->helper('file');
    write_file('<?php echo base_url();?>/downloads', $backup);
    $this->load->helper('download');
    force_download('mybackup.gz', $backup);
}
```

For your full application backup, do the same procedure with the following code:

```
function backup()
{
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $this->load->library('zip'); 
    $time = time(); 
    $this->zip->read_dir('D:xampp/htdocs/wms/');
    $this->zip->download('my_backup.'.$time.'.zip');
}
```

Here you can use any path of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public function backup(){
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $config = array(     
        'format'      => 'zip',             
        'filename'    => 'insert-file-name.sql'
    );

    $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($config); 

    $db_name = 'backup-on-'. date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") .'.zip';
    $save = 'uploads/'.$db_name;

    $this->load->helper('file');
    write_file($save, $backup); 
    $this->load->helper('download');
    force_download($db_name, $backup);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

$content = 'SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; START TRANSACTION; SET time_zone = "+00:00";';

```
    if($tables = $this->db->list_tables()){
        foreach($tables as $table){
            $content .= ' DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `' . $table . '`;';
            $content .= $this->db->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE ' . $table)->row_array()['Create Table'] . ';'; 
            $fields = $this->db->list_fields($table);
            $table_data = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table)->result_array();
            $insert_field = '';
            $insert_values = '';
            if($fields && $table_data){
                $insert_field .= 'INSERT INTO `' . $table . '` (';

                foreach($fields as $field){
                    $insert_field .= '`' . $field . '`,';
                }
                $insert_field = substr($insert_field,0,-1);
                $insert_field .= ')';
                
                $insert_values .= ' VALUES ';
                foreach($table_data as $table_row){
                    $insert_values .= '(' ;
                    foreach($table_row as $column => $value){
                        $insert_values .= "'" . addslashes($value) . "',";
                    }
                    $insert_values = substr($insert_values,0,-1);
                    $insert_values .= '),';
                }
                $insert_values = substr($insert_values,0,-1) . '; ';
            }
            $content .= $insert_field . $insert_values;
        }
    }
    $file_path = "./uploads/backup-" . date('Y-m-d') . ".sql";
    $myfile = fopen($file_path, "w");
    fwrite($myfile, $content);
    fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: Provide some clarification on your answer

Answer (score 0):

These lines have been grabbed from codeigniters documentation:

> Important:  In order to initialize the Utility class, your database
>   driver must already be running, since the utilities class relies on
>   it.

Please check if your database class is loaded or not when you call this function. Or you can put this line before loading the dbutil class `$this->load->database();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbname   = "raas";

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($dbname . "_" .date("Y-m-d_H-i-s").".sql"));

$command = "C:\AppServ\MySQL\bin\mysqldump --add-drop-table --host=$hostname   --user=$username --password=$password ".$dbname;

system($command);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to backup the database very early during bootstrapping.

I ran into the same problem when I tried to hack CodeIgniter into backing up my database using:

```
$prefs = array(
            'ignore'=> array('codes_cdt','codes_cpt','codes_icd10_dx_order','codes_icd10_pcs_order','pharma'),
            'format'=>'gzip','filename','add_drop'=> TRUE,'add_insert'=>TRUE,'newline'=> "\n");

$filename = APPPATH.'\\backups\\' .'backup-' . date('d-m-Y') . ' .gz';
if(!file_exists($filename)){
    get_instance()->load->dbutil();
    file_put_contents( $filename, $this->dbutil->backup($prefs));
}
```

at the bottom of my `config.php` file.

Move this to a model an allow it to autoload, and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?

// Try this one, this works FOR both codeigniter and core PHP

            public function Export_Database()
                {
                    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
                   // Load the file helper in codeigniter
                    $this->load->helper('file');


            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","databasename");

            $tables = array();
            $query = mysqli_query($con, 'SHOW TABLES');
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
                 $tables[] = $row[0];
            }

            $result = 'SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";';
            $result .= 'SET time_zone = "+00:00";';

            foreach($tables as $table){
            $query = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM `'.$table.'`');
            $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($query);

            $result .= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.';';
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con, 'SHOW CREATE TABLE `'.$table.'`'));
            $result .= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
               $result .= 'INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` VALUES(';
                 for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++){
                   $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                   $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                if(isset($row[$j])){
                       $result .= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; 
                    }else{ 
                        $result .= '""';
                    }
                    if($j<($num_fields-1)){ 
                        $result .= ',';
                    }
                }
                $result .= ");\n";
            }
            }
            $result .="\n\n";
            }

            //Create Folder
            $folder = 'database/';
            if (!is_dir($folder))
            mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
            chmod($folder, 0777);

            $date = date('m-d-Y'); 
            $filename = $folder."db_filename_".$date; 

            $handle = fopen($filename.'.sql','w+');
            fwrite($handle,$result);
            fclose($handle);
            redirect('Dashboard');           


                } // end Export_Database function
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to archive your database use the function $this->archive_database(); this function save the .sql file in the folder named archives in the root folder

```
// to intialize the path split the real path by dot .
        public function init_path($string){
            $array_path =  explode('.', $string);
            $realpath  = ''; 
            foreach ($array_path as $p)
            {
              
                $realpath .= $p;
                $realpath .= '/';
            }
            return $realpath;
            
        }
        
        // backup database function         
        public function archive_database($host = '',$user ='',$pass ='',$name ='', $path = '' , $download_allow = false ,       $tables=false, $backup_name=false){ 
            $CI = &get_instance();
            $CI->load->database();
            if($path != '')
            {
                $path = realpath($this->init_path($path));
                
            }else{
                if (!is_dir('archives/'))
            mkdir('archives/', 0777);
                $path = realpath($this->init_path('archives'));
            }
            if($host == '')
            {
                $host = $CI->db->hostname;
                
            }
            if($user == '')
            {
                $user = $CI->db->username;
                
            }
            if($pass == '')
            {
                $pass = $CI->db->password;
                
            }
            if($name == '')
            {
                $name = $CI->db->database;
                
            }
            
            set_time_limit(3000); 
            $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$name); 
            $mysqli->select_db($name);
            $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            $queryTables = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES');
            while($row = $queryTables->fetch_row()) { $target_tables[] = $row[0]; } 
            if($tables !== false)
                { $target_tables = array_intersect( $target_tables, $tables); } 
            $content = "SET SQL_MODE = \"NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO\";\r\nSET time_zone = \"+00:00\";\r\n\r\n\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;\r\n/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;\r\n--\r\n-- Database: `".$name."`\r\n--\r\n\r\n\r\n";
            foreach($target_tables as $table){
                if (empty($table)){ continue; } 
                $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `'.$table.'`');
                $fields_amount=$result->field_count; 
                $rows_num=$mysqli->affected_rows; 
                $res = $mysqli->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table);
                $TableMLine=$res->fetch_row(); 
                $content .= "\n\n".$TableMLine[1].";\n\n";
                for ($i = 0, $st_counter = 0; $i < $fields_amount;   $i++, $st_counter=0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_row())  { //when started (and every after 100 command cycle):
                        if ($st_counter%100 == 0 || $st_counter == 0 )  {$content .= "\nINSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES";}
                            $content .= "\n(";    for($j=0; $j<$fields_amount; $j++){ $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n", addslashes($row[$j]) ); if (isset($row[$j])){$content .= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ;}  else{$content .= '""';}     if ($j<($fields_amount-1)){$content.= ',';}   }        $content .=")";
                        //every after 100 command cycle [or at last line] ....p.s. but should be inserted 1 cycle eariler
                        if ( (($st_counter+1)%100==0 && $st_counter!=0) || $st_counter+1==$rows_num) {$content .= ";";} else {$content .= ",";} $st_counter=$st_counter+1;
                    }
                } $content .="\n\n\n";
            }
            $content .= "\r\n\r\n/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;\r\n/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;\r\n/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;";
            $backup_name = $backup_name ? $backup_name : $name."___(".date('H-i-s')."_".date('d-m-Y').")__rand".rand(1,11111111).".sql";
            
            $fileLocation = $path .'\\'. $backup_name;
            $file = fopen($fileLocation,"w");
            fwrite($file,$content);
            fclose($file);
            
            
            if($download_allow){
            ob_get_clean(); header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$backup_name."\"");
            }
            
            echo $content; exit;
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

No need to add `base_url()` at path

Comment: @CybernatiC  the question is  not say about base_url();.Your answer is not related to the question asked.