# How to backup the whole database 30mins once automattically?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.I have a function in a controller to backup the whole database. This happens only when I click a button. how to do this automattically.
This is my controller file.

```
public function backup_db()       
{
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $prefs = array(
                    'format'      => 'zip',
                    'filename'    => 'ospos.sql'
            );       
    $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);                
    $file_name =  'elfanto_billing-' . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") .'.zip';
    $save = 'uploads/'.$file_name;
    $this->load->helper('download');
    while (ob_get_level())
    {
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    force_download($file_name, $backup);
}
```

How to code for this? Can someone help me?

Comment: the word your looking for is `cron` often it takes only a word.

Comment: I am using windows. and have less idea about C-panel .web hosting is necessary for this?

Comment: no but triggering it on a timed basis is, obviously. I suggest looking up how to do that on windows.

Comment: windows has a scheduler

Comment: Can you give my some reference for it? @Dagon

Comment: google say: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is setup you script to run from the command line or `cli` then you can setup a simple timed cron job if on linux, using C-Panel or crond.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Answer (score 0):

You can set cron job for automation

Use:
php index.php Controller method

as command in your crontab. E.g.:

30 * * * * php /home/username/index.php welcome show

Source: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

Comment: should this be used in php page where I have the button to save my database.

Comment: you have to do it via shell, as you have to set crontab

Comment: if you use Cpanel or something like that, they may provide a GUI to set Cron Job too.

Comment: Here is a nice article that let you getting started with Cron Job : http://glennstovall.com/blog/2013/01/07/writing-cron-jobs-and-command-line-scripts-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You have to create cron job and set time to run every 30 mins and add following code

```
$this->load->dbutil();

        $prefs = array(     
                'format'      => 'zip',             
                'filename'    => 'my_db_backup.sql'
              );


        $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs); 

        $db_name = 'backup-on-'. date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") .'.zip';
        $save = 'pathtobkfolder/'.$db_name;

        $this->load->helper('file');
        write_file($save, $backup); 


        $this->load->helper('download');
        force_download($db_name, $backup);
```

http://w3facility.org/question/backup-mysql-database-with-codeigniter/

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html#backup-your-database

http://www-scf.usc.edu/~adportno/apache/htdocs/adportno/hw5/user_guide/database/utilities.html#backup

Answer (score -1):

@sundar nivash: please check this, it may be helpful.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093020/backup-mysql-database-with-codeigniter
```