# Backup MySQL database with CodeIgniter returns single query for each table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

I want to backup *MySQL* database with a script (*Cron*) with *CodeIgniter 3*.

But when I export as zip it will return each table records with single query. Not like we export from *MySQL* database. For example, if one table has 500 records, it will show 500 single queries instead of bunch of queries.

Please suggest, how to export database with script with output as we export from *MySQL*.

Comment: And what you have tried so far ? anyway do search on google https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNVz10VZf9Y

Comment: Follow this link : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096722/9255518

Comment: In this video, it will have same records like me. It will not affect with small database. But I have 25 MB database which will taking too much time for import again due to single query for each raw.

Comment: If you're doing it using cron, it might be easier just to use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html) directly? Then you don't need to involve CodeIgniter or PHP at all.

Comment: You've tagged phpMyAdmin, but that isn't an appropriate tool to use in this case. The phpMyAdmin application is intended to be used interactively by administrators, not called through a script. I agree with Magnus that mysqldump is by far the best tool for the job.